# Plot ROC Curve for a prediction set of one class

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, roc

I built a neural network to perform anomaly detection on a time series that has all anomaly values. This means, that the **y_test** is an array with all 1's inside it. Since the neural network classified it all correctly, I also have a prediction set with all 1's (obviously it has the same shape of the y_test). When I try to create the **ROC plot** I get the warning:

> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py:941: UndefinedMetricWarning: No negative samples in y_true, false positive value should be meaningless
> warnings.warn("No negative samples in y_true, "

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn.metrics as metrics

y_test = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
preds = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
fpr, tpr, threshold = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, preds)
roc_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, 'b', label = 'AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'r--')
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.show()
```

The resultant graph is empty:
[image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: Not sure how to answer your question, but you *will* need some normal points (0) to build a roc curve. And also to train your model. Otherwise it may classify everything as an anomaly (1), which isn't particularly useful...

Comment: While not solves your problem, for `roc_curve` function, should provide the probabilities as second parameter, not predicted classes.